# Headers already sent on a frontend post form using wp_redirect before get_header

Tags: forms, front-end, headers, wp-redirect

I've gone through the various issues with headers already sent, checking for white space and making sure that the get_header line appears after the wp_redirect but I'm stuck.

The code is:

```
<?php if ( !is_user_logged_in()) { 
        include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/member.php'); 
    } else { ?>
<?php
if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) &&  $_POST['action'] == "new_post") {
    // Do some minor form validation to make sure there is content
    if (isset ($_POST['title'])) {
        $title =  $_POST['title'];
    } else {
        echo 'Please enter a title';

    $tags = $_POST['post_tags'];

    // ADD THE FORM INPUT TO $new_post ARRAY
    $new_post = array(
    'post_title'    =>  $title,
    'post_content'  =>  $description,
    'post_category' =>  array($_POST['cat']),  // Usable for custom taxonomies too
    'tags_input'    =>  array($tags),
    'post_status'   =>  'draft',           // Choose: publish, preview, future, draft, etc.
    'post_type' =>  'post',  //'post',page' or use a custom post type if you want to
    );

    //SAVE THE POST
    $pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);

    //KEEPS OUR COMMA SEPARATED TAGS AS INDIVIDUAL
    wp_set_post_tags($pid, $_POST['post_tags']);

    //REDIRECT TO THE NEW POST ON SAVE
    $link = include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/thankyou.php'); 
    wp_redirect( $link );

    //INSERT OUR MEDIA ATTACHMENTS
    if ($_FILES) {
        foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
        $newupload = insert_attachment($file,$pid);
        }

    } // END THE IF STATEMENT FOR FILES

} // END THE IF STATEMENT THAT STARTED THE WHOLE FORM

//POST THE POST YO
do_action('wp_insert_post', 'wp_insert_post');

?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div id="content" role="main">
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="post">
                <div class="title">
                    <h2>Post</h2>
                </div>
            <div class="form-content">

            <div>
                <form id="new_post" name="new_post" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <fieldset name="name">
                    <label for="title">Title:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="title" value="" tabindex="5" name="title" />
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset class="tax">
                    <label for="cat">Category:</label>
                    <?php wp_dropdown_categories( 'tab_index=10&taxonomy=type&hide_empty=0' ); ?>
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset class="content">
                    <label for="description">Description:</label>
                    <textarea id="description" tabindex="15" name="description" cols="60" rows="10"></textarea>
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset class="images">
                    <label for="company_logo">Company Logo</label>
                    <input type="file" name="company_logo" id="company_logo" tabindex="25" />
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset class="submit">
                    <input type="submit" value="Post It" tabindex="40" id="psubmit" name="submit" />
                </fieldset>

                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="new_post" />
                <?php wp_nonce_field( 'new-post' ); ?>

                </form>
            </div>

            </div><!-- .entry-content -->
        </div><!-- #post-## -->

    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
    </div><!-- #content -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
<?php } ?> <!-- user is logged in -->
```

If the post status is set to draft and the redirect to thankyou.php, I get the headers already sent message. The post gets saved and the thankyou.php page is displayed but the headers already sent message appears.

If I set the post status to publish and the redirect to something like:

```
$link = get_permalink( $pid );
    wp_redirect( $link );
    exit;
```

Then the form works without a hitch and displays the published post.

I want to be able to review the post before it gets published, that's why I want the status sent to draft and a message to appear to the poster.

How do I accomplish this?

Debugging info:

```
Notice: Undefined index: post_tags in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\wp-content\themes\testtheme\postform.php on line 31
Notice: Undefined variable: description in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\wp-content\themes\testtheme\postform.php on line 48
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\wp-includes\post.php on line 2915
Notice: Undefined index: mytheme_meta_box_nonce in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\wp-content\themes\testtheme\lib\metabox.php on line 177
```

Comment: What should `$link = include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/thankyou.php');` do? You're then calling `wp_redirect( $link );`, while what I guess you want to do is simply `wp_redirect(TEMPLATEPATH . '/thankyou.php');`, no? In addition, you have to call `exit;` after the redirect. And the code after the redirect (INSERT OF MEDIA ATTACHMENTS) won't be executed, anyway.

Comment: Please add [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress). My guess is that you have a `Warning` echoing-- possibly the `$tags = $_POST['post_tags'];` line as you use that key without checking for its existence. Or maybe its the explicit echo just above that line.

Comment: I've added some debugging info. How do I check for the existence of the key?

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
 echo 'Please enter a title';
```

Remove this line & check your output.

Comment: Can you explain this better? I don't get it: add-remove-test shouldn't be add-test-remove?

Comment: Is a common error which means you are basically sending request multiple times.so error occur.

Comment: That is a possibility but not the only one. Claiming that "this will work" is a much stronger statement than the available evidence supports. Yes, that is sloppy, but my money is on the line following that one... but that is a guess too.

Comment: I've updated the question with debugging info and it seems that s_ha_dum is on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Use init hook...

```
<?php
function custom12345_wp_insert_post()
{
    if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) &&  $_POST['action'] == "new_post") {
        // Do some minor form validation to make sure there is content
        if (isset ($_POST['title'])) {
            $title =  $_POST['title'];
        } else {
            echo 'Please enter a title';

        $tags = $_POST['post_tags'];

        // ADD THE FORM INPUT TO $new_post ARRAY
        $new_post = array(
        'post_title'    =>  $title,
        'post_content'  =>  $description,
        'post_category' =>  array($_POST['cat']),  // Usable for custom taxonomies too
        'tags_input'    =>  array($tags),
        'post_status'   =>  'draft',           // Choose: publish, preview, future, draft, etc.
        'post_type' =>  'post',  //'post',page' or use a custom post type if you want to
        );

        //SAVE THE POST
        $pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);

        //KEEPS OUR COMMA SEPARATED TAGS AS INDIVIDUAL
        wp_set_post_tags($pid, $_POST['post_tags']);

        //INSERT OUR MEDIA ATTACHMENTS
        if ($_FILES) {
            foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
            $newupload = insert_attachment($file,$pid);
            }

        } // END THE IF STATEMENT FOR FILES

        //REDIRECT TO THE NEW POST ON SAVE
        $link = include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/thankyou.php'); 
        wp_redirect( $link );
        exit;

     } // END THE IF STATEMENT THAT STARTED THE WHOLE FORM
    }
}
add_action('init','custom12345_wp_insert_post');
?>

<?php if ( !is_user_logged_in()) { 
        include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/member.php'); 
    } else { ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <div id="content" role="main">
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="post">
                <div class="title">
                    <h2>Post</h2>
                </div>
            <div class="form-content">

            <div>
                <form id="new_post" name="new_post" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <fieldset name="name">
                    <label for="title">Title:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="title" value="" tabindex="5" name="title" />
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset class="tax">
                    <label for="cat">Category:</label>
                    <?php wp_dropdown_categories( 'tab_index=10&taxonomy=type&hide_empty=0' ); ?>
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset class="content">
                    <label for="description">Description:</label>
                    <textarea id="description" tabindex="15" name="description" cols="60" rows="10"></textarea>
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset class="images">
                    <label for="company_logo">Company Logo</label>
                    <input type="file" name="company_logo" id="company_logo" tabindex="25" />
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset class="submit">
                    <input type="submit" value="Post It" tabindex="40" id="psubmit" name="submit" />
                </fieldset>

                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="new_post" />
                <?php wp_nonce_field( 'new-post' ); ?>

                </form>
            </div>

            </div><!-- .entry-content -->
        </div><!-- #post-## -->

    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
    </div><!-- #content -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
<?php } ?> <!-- user is logged in -->
```

Comment: Some more explanatory context around the code would be helpful. Why should the OP hook into `'init'`?

Comment: init is called before anything is sent to output, so wraping code into init hook, you will get rid of header allready sent error..

Comment: I tried your code but it doesn't work. The thank you page doesn't load and the post isn't saved.